# How do we use query configurations while using SQL client in Flink SQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, retention

How do we use query configurations while using SQL client in Flink SQL?

The same fashion as mentioned in the link below for 
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/query_configuration.html

Want to use Idle state retention time.

Answer (score 1):

Flink's SQL client can read a YAML configuration file on startup, and this file can include idle state retention specifications. For example, you might start the client via

`sql-client.sh embedded -e sql-client-config.yaml`

where the config file contains

```
execution:
  planner: old                      # optional: either 'old' (default) or 'blink'
  type: streaming                   # required: execution mode either 'batch' or 'streaming'
  result-mode: table                # required: either 'table' or 'changelog'
  max-table-result-rows: 1000000    # optional: maximum number of maintained rows in
                                    #   'table' mode (1000000 by default, smaller 1 means unlimited)
  time-characteristic: event-time   # optional: 'processing-time' or 'event-time' (default)
  parallelism: 1                    # optional: Flink's parallelism (1 by default)
  periodic-watermarks-interval: 200 # optional: interval for periodic watermarks (200 ms by default)
  min-idle-state-retention: 0       # optional: table program's minimum idle state time
  max-idle-state-retention: 0       # optional: table program's maximum idle state time
```

See [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sqlClient.html#environment-files) for more details.

Comment: Thanks David for replying back quick.

Does this min-idle-state-retention, max-idle-state-retention holds appropriate for query like

SELECT sourceKafka.* FROM sourceKafka INNER JOIN badips ON sourceKafka.`source.ip`=badips.ip
WHERE sourceKafka.timestamp_received BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Since there is no grouping and I read that these parameters define for how long the **state of a key** is retained

Comment: For a join like that, each stream will be keyed by the ip, so yes, this will be keyed state that is subject to the state retention policy. But moreover, you don't need to bother with this, because with a time windowed join, Flink SQL will automatically clear older records that have become irrelevant.

Comment: Time windowed join, Flink SQL will automatically clear older records that have become irrelevant => That is what I also thought so... but when i tried the above query, 60+GB heap space runs out. Don't know why

Comment: That's potentially a rather complex topic, not well suited for stack overflow. Suggest you ask for help on the user mailing list.

Comment: Sure David. Thanks

Comment: Got a response from one of the flink team members.

Been advised for using temporal tables for similar usecase
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html